# python on-demand http server

Tags: python, server, http

I am creating auto tests for application (with python, that i am not so familiar with).

Simplified logic:

1. Start application
2. Start my service
3. Send request for that application to perform task
4. Application send to my service http request with some info

I totally have no idea what to use. After small research i found tornado, but it looks like overkill lib for my task.

Can someone recommend that kind of lib for python (with official documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a web server built-in. Maybe this is all what you need.

On the Command Line,

- Change to the directory where your interesting files are.
- run:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8808 > /tmp/simple-web-server.log 2>&1 &`

- Send your requests to `http://localhost:8808` or `http://123.45.67.89:8808`

(whatever your IP is. Maybe you prefer to use the hostname. YMMV.)

You can use any other port number rather than 8808, but avoid numbers < 1024 because they are "privileged ports".

If you have only python3, run

`python3 -m http.server 8808 --bind 127.0.0.1 > /tmp/simple-web-server.log 2>&1 &`

and open your browser here: `http://localhost:8808`

Comment: i tryed, but call "serve_forever" block script execution